# How to make a cookie be on the whole site instead of being on a specific page/

Tags: php, functions, wp-enqueue-style, cookies

So I had an idea to make a button that swaps between css files in order to do random stuff such as making 2 backgrounds that the site users will be able to swap between.

I had no idea how to do it, so I went over to google and watched some php guides, and I kinda copied most of the code while making a few changes.

This is what I ended up with:

On the functions.php file I got this:

```
function style_1_or_2(){

    $style = isset($_GET['style']) && in_array($_GET['style'], array('style2', 'normal')) ?  $_GET['style'] : (isset($_COOKIE['style']) && in_array($_COOKIE['style'], array('style2', 'normal'))  ? $_COOKIE['style'] : 'default_case');

    if ($style == 'style2'){
        function the_other_css(){
            wp_enqueue_style('the_other_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style2.css');
            setcookie('style', 'style2', time()+31536000);
        }
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'the_other_css', 999);
    } else {
        function default_css(){
            wp_enqueue_style('default_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
            setcookie('style', 'normal', time()+31536000);
        }
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'default_css', 999);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'style_1_or_2');
```

And I also added 2 buttons on my side menu, which are

```
<a href="?style=normal">style1</a>
<a href="?style=style2">style2</a>
```

Now, it works fine for the most part, BUT, it's kinda page specific.
For an example, if I click on the "style2" button on the homepage, I can refresh it and I'll still get the "style2" file as long as I'll stay at the home page. but once I go to any other page on the site, I will get the default style, which is "style1", and I'll have to click the "style2" button again on that page, and I'll still get the default style "style1" on any other page besides the homepage and the page I just was at and clicked it there too.

I tried to do some stuff to fix it but I'm kinda noob so I didn't really succeeded, and now I'm here asking for some help.

(sorry for my bad English, not my main language)

Comment: You shouldn't be defining functions inside functions, don't nest it's unnecesary and makes it confusing to read

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a path and domain,

`setcookie('style', 'style2', time()+31536000, '/', '.example.com');`

Replace `.example.com` with your sites hostname.

Further reading: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php